# Bulk Email Limited to 80 Emails (GMAIL)?

Tags: smtp, gmail

Gmail list their email limits here:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en

However, I am getting an SMTP Exception with little more info than "failure sending mail". It is happening at the 80 email mark, when attempting to rapidly send a bulk volume of emails.

My error catching is:

```
       try
            {
                fLogFile.Add("Before smtp.Send");
                smtp.Send(mail);
                fLogFile.Add("After smtp.Send");
                Result.SentCount = 1;
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                fLogFile.Add("Argument Null Exception");
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException e)
            {
                fLogFile.Add("Argument Exception");
            }
            catch (System.ObjectDisposedException e)
            {
                fLogFile.Add("Object Disposed Exception");
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException e)
            {
                fLogFile.Add("SMTP failed recipients exception");
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                fLogFile.Add("Invalid Operation Exception");
            }
            catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException e)
            {
                fLogFile.Add("Smtp Exception");
                fLogFile.Add(e.Message);
            }
```

Can anyone confirm if 80 emails is a bulk limitation? I haven't seen Google state any limits on rapid email requests.

Comment: Yes, I have experienced the same, after 80 emails an SMTP exemption is thrown. I think to slow down helps a bit.

Comment: Here is a similar observation from a Java user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756808/bulk-emails-failed-with-421-4-7-0-try-again-later

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a per minute limit for sending SMPT messages via Gmail (around [80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756808/bulk-emails-failed-with-421-4-7-0-try-again-later) (had the same experience) to [100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365904/nodemailer-gmail-connection-closed-with-high-number-of-mails)).

First, check your message queue in G Suite admin area. If the queue is huge and still growing you send too fast.

Some useful links:

- G Suite [SMTP Error Reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en)
- Gmail [Bandwidth limits for accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en)
- [Gmail sending limits in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)
- [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

There is no further explanation what's wrong when you suffer from the error

> 421, "4.7.0", Try again later, closing connection.

In general, Gmail may slow-down or reject your emails if you:

- send too large volumes of email.
- suddenly change your email volume.
- send email to spam honeypot addresses.
- send email to unknown users.
- your server’s IP is on a public blacklist.
- Gmail users marking your messages as spam.
- use a new IP address to send emails.
- your DNS settings are incorrect.

Moral: If sending a large amount of email, it's probably best to use your own email server.