# Bulk Emails failed with 421 4.7.0 Try again later

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, gmail-api

I have a requirement to send bulk emails with in my organization. I am Java Mail API and sending the mails with below config.

```
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

Mail#1 
From: abc@org.com
To: emp1@org.com

Mail#2 
From: abc@org.com
To: emp2@org.com

...

Mails are triggered in a loop.

Problem: 
First 80 emails sent successfully. From 81st mail I am failing with below error for 10-15 emails and later few mails are sent successfully.

Out of 743 emails 400 Failed & 343 are success.

```
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/18 07:25:54 | com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (MAIL) xsdsfasdsa.96 - gsmtp
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/18 07:25:54 | 
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/18 07:25:54 |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/18 07:25:54 |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/08/18 07:25:54 |   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
```

1. Help me how to resolve it.
2. Is there any specific **per minute limit** on smtp.gmail.com?

**Thanks,
Rana**

Comment: Wouldn't "bulk emails" mean "email with multiple recipients", not "a huge amount of emails"?

Comment: the mail contains person details so I can't make it with multiple recipients

Comment: Ok then. Check out the [google's guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en) for bulk sending, see if you can address any of those.

Comment: @ranafeb14 was the answer helpful? to you?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I think there is a per minute limit for sending SMPT messages via Gmail (around 80 in my experience that of others around [80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744892/bulk-email-limited-to-80-emails-gmail)-[100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365904/nodemailer-gmail-connection-closed-with-high-number-of-mails)). But it's not a 100% hard limit but some sort of soft limit that is enforced when Gmail thinks its due.

First, check your message queue in G Suite admin area. If the queue is huge and still growing you send too fast.

Some useful links:

- G Suite [SMTP Error Reference](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en)
- Gmail [Bandwidth limits for accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en)
- [Gmail sending limits in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)
- [Bulk Senders Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en)

There is no further explanation what's wrong when you suffer from the error

> 421, "4.7.0", Try again later, closing connection.

General recommendations:

- you could use Pooled SMTP like https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/

> If pooling is used then Nodemailer keeps a fixed amount of connections
>   open and sends the next message once a connection becomes available.
>   It is most useful when you have a large number of messages that you
>   want to send in batches or your provider allows you to only use a
>   small amount of parallel connections.

- do not send too fast
- do not send more than 50 emails at once
- do not assume Gmail is a local system. It's an external service that uses sophisticated methods to make email globally available extending a 42-year-old invention that is far from perfect.
- do not try stupid things or Gmail will punish you.

Moral: If sending a large amount of email, it's probably best to use your own email server.

Comment: using pool: true option was the solution for my issue. Thanks!