# error Server terminates connection response=421 4.7.0 Try again later

Tags: node.js, smtp, gmail, gmail-api

response=421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) vj23-20020a170907131700b0078db51bb303sm9553ejb.86 - gsmtp: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) vj23-20020a170907131700b0078db51bb303sm9553ejb.86 - gsmtp Error: Server terminates connection. response=421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) vj23-20020a170907131700b0078db51bb303sm9553ejb.86 - gsmtp: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) vj23-20020a170907131700b0078db51bb303sm9553ejb.86 - gsmtp

[image]

Comment: So did you try later? What happened? Did you do a web search for this? How are you sending, what volume in what time frame? How is your IP address reputation? Is this even about programming?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk Emails failed with 421 4.7.0 Try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756808/bulk-emails-failed-with-421-4-7-0-try-again-later)

Comment: thanks Robert but it not worked for me

Comment: I found a solution I hope it will help you I replaced nodemailer Smtp by emailjs and this will solve the problem.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced nodemailer Smtp by [emailjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emailjs).

Answer (score 2):

I believe Nodemailer uses the computer's hostname in place of the `name` property when creating a transport. This can cause issues with some email relays such as Gmail. To fix this you can explicitly set the `name` property in the SMTP transport options to an arbitrary string.

Comment: This is what worked for me.

host: "smtp-relay.gmail.com",
Port: 465,
secure: true,
name: "example.com"    (replace with your domain)